# Kenrel error installing Ubuntu on VirtualBox

Tags: system-installation, kernel, virtualbox

I am trying to install Ubuntu 20.04 on my virtual box appa and this is the error message I get when I press start.

What should I do? [image]

Thank you!

Comment: Have you executed the command shown in the right dialog?

Comment: yes and I don't get a result. It says that I have to reinstall  virtualbox-dkms package but I don't know what it is.

Comment: What is the host OS?

Comment: If you mean the OS I am using, it is Ubuntu 20.10 but I also tried it in Ubuntu 20.04 and had the same issue.